# CSS transitions/transforms not affecting required elements

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm just trying to get to grips with advanced transitions and transforms and having a little trouble with a section I'm working on. I have everything working as required except I have an h5 over the image which I do NOT want to change/transform but I do want the image to still transform.

My fiddle should illustrate better than words - http://jsfiddle.net/28m3fpcv/2

And the code

```
.news-container {
    background: #2a2a2a;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 30px 5%;
}

.news-photo {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333333333%;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.news-photo img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.news-photo img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}

.news-photo a {
    display: block;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.news-photo h5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    font-size: 1.063em;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="news-container cf">

            <article class="news-photo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x576"/>
                    <h5>Story Title</h5>
                </a>
            </article>

            <article class="news-photo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x576"/>
                    <h5>Story Title</h5>
                </a>
            </article>

            <article class="news-photo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x576"/>
                    <h5>Story Title</h5>
                </a>
            </article>

            <article class="news-photo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x576"/>
                    <h5>Story Title</h5>
                </a>
            </article>

            <article class="news-photo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x576"/>
                    <h5>Story Title</h5>
                </a>
            </article>

            <article class="news-photo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x576"/>
                    <h5>Story Title</h5>
                </a>
            </article>
        </div>
```

If you hover over the text, the image transform reverts back. Is there any way I can not have that happen but still leave the heading alone? I tried placing the H5 outside the anchor but then obviously that isn't clickable. I want the whole thing clickable, the H5 to remain as is and the image to do the transform.

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry I should probably clarify further. The image hover is indeed working fine, the issue is when your mouse gets to the text, the zoom resets, and vice versa. The effect I'd like to achieve is that when you hover anywhere in the box, including the text, the image zoom remains but I don't want the zoom effect on the text, that should remain the original size.

Comment: Your fiddle is working for me in chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: I perhaps wasn't 100% clear. The problem is that when you hover the text the image zoom resets to normal, and then happens again when you move back over the image. I'd like it so that the zoom stays when you hover the text.

Comment: Fiddle also works in Firefox 40.0.2 on MacOSX 10.8.5

Comment: Yeah, I see what you are talking about now and I dont know how you would fix it , however the answer will be in javascript i think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think you can but you would have to change this

```
.news-photo img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

to this

```
.news-photo a:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/28m3fpcv/5/)

Answer (score -1):

When adding `transform: scale(1)` to `.news-photo img` you should be fine.
It helps the browser to understand where to start the transformation and where to end it when the `:hover` state is being triggered.